# ¿Como hago para que en un procedimiento almacenado pueda guardar en dos variables con INTO frente a una consulta que regresa una o varas columnas?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, select

**Explico:** resulta que tengo una *procedure* que establece dos parámetro enteros, los cuales luego se disponen a almacenar cada uno el resultado de un solo valor que provienen de columnas diferentes una por cada uno, el `select` que tengo es algo complejo, así que dejaré un código mas bien resumido, donde se pueda comprender lo que quisiera hacer en caso de que se pudiera:

```
DECLARE idUsuario INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE idRepuesto INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT us.id_usuario INTO idUsuario, us.id_cidudad INTO idCiudad
FROM usuarios as us
WHERE us.id_usuario = 1;

#Comprobando que se guardo bien
SELECT idUsuario; 
SELECT idCiudad;

#Resultado esperado
/* Primer Select 
 _________
|idUsuario|
-----------
|    1    |  
-----------
Segundo Select
 _________
|idCiudad|
-----------
|    10   |  
-----------

*/
```

No sé si se pueda hacer en caso de no poderse agradezco que me aclararan el porqué, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede y lo harias de esta forma:

```
SELECT us.id_usuario, us.id_cidudad
INTO  idUsuario, idCiudad
FROM usuarios as us
WHERE us.id_usuario = 1;
```

Comment: ¡Gracias había intentando varias formas y nada jajaja!